# KeyError: 'base_score' while fitting XGBClassifier

Tags: python, grid-search, xgbclassifier

Using Gridsearch I find the most optimal hyperparameters after fitting my training data:

```
model_xgb = XGBClassifier()
n_estimators = [50, 100, 150, 200]
max_depth = [2, 4, 6, 8]
param_grid = dict(max_depth=max_depth, n_estimators=n_estimators)
kfold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=7)
grid_search = GridSearchCV(model_xgb, param_grid, scoring="neg_log_loss", n_jobs=-1, cv=kfold, verbose=1)
grid_result = grid_search.fit(train_X, y_train)
```

The best answer is obtained by using `{'max_depth': 4, 'n_estimators': 50}`. That's why I create a new model with these hyperparameters:

```
model_xgb_tn = XGBClassifier(n_estimators=50,max_depth=4,objective='multi:softprob')
```

When I try to fit the model to my data: `model_xgb_tn.fit(train_X,y_train)`, I receive a `KeyError: 'base_score'`. I just wasn't able to understand why I got a KeyError when I even didn't use the hyperparameter.

Below is the error code:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\formatters.py in __call__(self, obj, include, exclude)
    968 
    969             if method is not None:
--> 970                 return method(include=include, exclude=exclude)
    971             return None
    972         else:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py in _repr_mimebundle_(self, **kwargs)
    461     def _repr_mimebundle_(self, **kwargs):
    462         """Mime bundle used by jupyter kernels to display estimator"""
--> 463         output = {"text/plain": repr(self)}
    464         if get_config()["display"] == 'diagram':
    465             output["text/html"] = estimator_html_repr(self)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py in __repr__(self, N_CHAR_MAX)
    277             n_max_elements_to_show=N_MAX_ELEMENTS_TO_SHOW)
    278 
--> 279         repr_ = pp.pformat(self)
    280 
    281         # Use bruteforce ellipsis when there are a lot of non-blank characters

~\Anaconda3\lib\pprint.py in pformat(self, object)
    142     def pformat(self, object):
    143         sio = _StringIO()
--> 144         self._format(object, sio, 0, 0, {}, 0)
    145         return sio.getvalue()
    146 

~\Anaconda3\lib\pprint.py in _format(self, object, stream, indent, allowance, context, level)
    159             self._readable = False
    160             return
--> 161         rep = self._repr(object, context, level)
    162         max_width = self._width - indent - allowance
    163         if len(rep) > max_width:

~\Anaconda3\lib\pprint.py in _repr(self, object, context, level)
    391     def _repr(self, object, context, level):
    392         repr, readable, recursive = self.format(object, context.copy(),
--> 393                                                 self._depth, level)
    394         if not readable:
    395             self._readable = False

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\_pprint.py in format(self, object, context, maxlevels, level)
    168     def format(self, object, context, maxlevels, level):
    169         return _safe_repr(object, context, maxlevels, level,
--> 170                           changed_only=self._changed_only)
    171 
    172     def _pprint_estimator(self, object, stream, indent, allowance, context,

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\_pprint.py in _safe_repr(object, context, maxlevels, level, changed_only)
    412         recursive = False
    413         if changed_only:
--> 414             params = _changed_params(object)
    415         else:
    416             params = object.get_params(deep=False)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\_pprint.py in _changed_params(estimator)
     96     init_params = {name: param.default for name, param in init_params.items()}
     97     for k, v in params.items():
---> 98         if (repr(v) != repr(init_params[k]) and
     99                 not (is_scalar_nan(init_params[k]) and is_scalar_nan(v))):
    100             filtered_params[k] = v

KeyError: 'base_score'

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\formatters.py in __call__(self, obj)
    700                 type_pprinters=self.type_printers,
    701                 deferred_pprinters=self.deferred_printers)
--> 702             printer.pretty(obj)
    703             printer.flush()
    704             return stream.getvalue()

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\lib\pretty.py in pretty(self, obj)
    400                         if cls is not object \
    401                                 and callable(cls.__dict__.get('__repr__')):
--> 402                             return _repr_pprint(obj, self, cycle)
    403 
    404             return _default_pprint(obj, self, cycle)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\lib\pretty.py in _repr_pprint(obj, p, cycle)
    695     """A pprint that just redirects to the normal repr function."""
    696     # Find newlines and replace them with p.break_()
--> 697     output = repr(obj)
    698     for idx,output_line in enumerate(output.splitlines()):
    699         if idx:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py in __repr__(self, N_CHAR_MAX)
    277             n_max_elements_to_show=N_MAX_ELEMENTS_TO_SHOW)
    278 
--> 279         repr_ = pp.pformat(self)
    280 
    281         # Use bruteforce ellipsis when there are a lot of non-blank characters

~\Anaconda3\lib\pprint.py in pformat(self, object)
    142     def pformat(self, object):
    143         sio = _StringIO()
--> 144         self._format(object, sio, 0, 0, {}, 0)
    145         return sio.getvalue()
    146 

~\Anaconda3\lib\pprint.py in _format(self, object, stream, indent, allowance, context, level)
    159             self._readable = False
    160             return
--> 161         rep = self._repr(object, context, level)
    162         max_width = self._width - indent - allowance
    163         if len(rep) > max_width:

~\Anaconda3\lib\pprint.py in _repr(self, object, context, level)
    391     def _repr(self, object, context, level):
    392         repr, readable, recursive = self.format(object, context.copy(),
--> 393                                                 self._depth, level)
    394         if not readable:
    395             self._readable = False

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\_pprint.py in format(self, object, context, maxlevels, level)
    168     def format(self, object, context, maxlevels, level):
    169         return _safe_repr(object, context, maxlevels, level,
--> 170                           changed_only=self._changed_only)
    171 
    172     def _pprint_estimator(self, object, stream, indent, allowance, context,

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\_pprint.py in _safe_repr(object, context, maxlevels, level, changed_only)
    412         recursive = False
    413         if changed_only:
--> 414             params = _changed_params(object)
    415         else:
    416             params = object.get_params(deep=False)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\_pprint.py in _changed_params(estimator)
     96     init_params = {name: param.default for name, param in init_params.items()}
     97     for k, v in params.items():
---> 98         if (repr(v) != repr(init_params[k]) and
     99                 not (is_scalar_nan(init_params[k]) and is_scalar_nan(v))):
    100             filtered_params[k] = v

KeyError: 'base_score'
```

Comment: This seems to be a known issue: https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/5665. Does updating scikit-learn help?

Answer (score 0):

You need to give a base score parameter, for the first iteration of gradient boosting, you can think of it as an initial weight to start with. For regression, it's the average of your target column and for classification problems, it's 1/(number of classes). You can refer to [documentation of xgboost](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parameter.html) for more information about this hyperparameter.

Comment: Good point! I should have added that to the description but I got the error even though I specified `base_score` as 0.5.

Comment: maybe your hyperparameters are conflicting, I don’t know in depth but it could be something like the base score you’re giving is conflicting with the objective function or other hyperparameters. did you find out what is wrong by the way?